# Sql SELECT statement inside echo

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to get the information of the member who do the transaction. In the page, the member information I have only their username with the session such `$member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];`

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    $member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
    $total = 0;
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';

                    <!---- THIS IS WHERE I PUT THE INFO OF USERNAME ---->
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="member_name" value="'.$member_name.'"/>';

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_name[]" value="'.$cart_itm["name"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_price[]" value="'.$cart_itm["price"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_quantity[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'"/></td>';                           
                    $totalPerEach = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_eachTotal[]" value="'.$totalPerEach.'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Inside the echo of SESSION of Products, I want to get the further detail information of the member, such as the address, the password and etc.

```
    echo ' <!---- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO WRITE SQL SELECT STATEMENT ---->
           <div id="process-to-detail">
               <div id="user-information">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Your Name is</td>
                            <td>Your Address is</td>
                            <td>Your Phone is</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </div>
          </div>';
```

In the comment above inside the echo, I want to write a sql statement to get the further detail of member which the point is `select * from member_list where member_name=$_SESSION['member_name'];`

Please tell me is it possible to make sql statement inside echo '...'; If it is not, how to get the member detail info.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Execute the query before echoing.

Comment: uh, you can echo out any sql statement you want. sql's just text, after all. if you want to EXECUTE that query and echo out the results, that's an entirely different thing.

Comment: See [MySQL Basic Example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php)

Comment: @showdev thanks. Can I wirte two sql select statement before echoing. For example before echoing I have executed first  statement: `select from table_one {query  here}`, and then I to execute the second query: `select from table_two {query here}`?

Comment: Sure, although you might be able to combine them into one query. Depends on what you're selecting. I suggest that you give it a try, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @MarcB thanks, I've got to remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the functionality you're trying to introduce in a function and then call it.

Example

```
    function getMyUserData($member_name)  {
        $myUserDataString = false;  // Default value.
        // your database connectivity
        $dbconn = new mysqli('server','user','password','database');
        // Sanitize your input to avoid SQL injection issues.
        $member_name = $dbconn->real_escape_string($member_name);
        // your sql statement
        //It would be better to use a unique id instead of a name.
        $sql = "SELECT `password`, `address` FROM `USERS` WHERE " .
            "`member_name` = '$member_name' LIMIT 1";  
        // execute query
        $result = $dbconn->query($sql);
        // check for query result
        if(is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0)  {
            // Get data from result.
            $myUserData = $result->fetch_assoc();
            // Free the result
            $result->free;
            // Access the fields you wanted
            $myUserDataString = "My user address: " . htmlentities($myUserData['address']);
            //You may echo the string here to cause the function to output your text
            // or return the value and echo it.  In this case we will return the value.
        }
        return $myUserDataString;
}
echo getMyUserData($_SESSION['member_name']);
```

I hope this helps..

P.S.  It's generally not a good idea to return the password to the client.  Try using hash or crypt for one way encryption.

See the following links for details:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Hi Joel Caton,many thanks for this answer. But is this function is written inside echo like `echo 'above funtion';` or what?

Comment: You may `echo getMyUserData($_SESSION['member_name']);` to output the string you assign to `$MyUserDataString` in the function. Echo just outputs the string you give it regardless of how you created it.  Therefore `echo "My string"; is treated the same as `echo $MyStringVariable;`.  We are creating the string from the database query result in the function. Take a look at [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) in the php manual for a little more information.

Comment: I have an error in this line: `if(is_object($result && $result->num_rows > 0)  {`

Comment: Sorry about that @klaudia.  I should have wrote the code example in my IDE.  I missed closing the is_object call with ).  Change it to `if(is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0)  {` and it will work.

Comment: That's alright. I have used different method for this. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Thanks. :)